# AppleScript to get value of active cell from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, applescript

Trying to get the value of current highlighted cell from Excel worksheet

```
set x to null
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet "Sheet1" of active workbook
       set x to value of active cell as string
       display dialog x
    end tell
end tell
```

Above AppleScript sets x as "missing value". What am I doing wrong here, is there some other way to get the value of active cell?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2011 for MAC version 14.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in excel's applescript dictionary you will see that "active cell" is a property of the application. It's not a property of a worksheet or workbook. So this works...

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set x to value of active cell as string
    display dialog x
end tell
```

It's also a property of a window so this works too...

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell window 1
        set x to value of active cell as string
        display dialog x
    end tell
end tell
```